# Обратный вывод данных из DLL

Tags: java, delphi, dll, jna

Столкнулся с проблемой вывода данных из DLL.
Есть файл с интерфейсом и вызовом функций (написан на делфи, думаю что DLL так же).

И так, вот есть нижеследующий код с примера на делфи:

```
{получить назначенное на счёт сообщение}
Function GetAccountMessage( Account: Integer; var Msg: PChar ): BOOL; stdcall;
```

И реализация моего кода на Java: (передаём номер аккаунта, должны получить строку обратно)

```
CscLink INSTANCE = (CscLink) Native.loadLibrary("csclink", CscLink.class, W32APIOptions.ASCII_OPTIONS);    
boolean GetAccountMessage(int Account, StringByReference Msg);
```

Далее вызываю в main

```
    StringByReference getAccMsg = new StringByReference();
    myLib.GetAccountMessage(getAccNumb.getValue(), getAccMsg);
    System.out.println("Сообщение: " + getAccMsg.getValue());
```

После чего приходит следующий ответ:

> 4Днk/inPЁХ   a

Так же хочу подметить, что вариации этого ответа прилетают всегда разные, но всегда спереди указано *4Д*
Пробовал использовать указатели и прочие. 
Класс StringByReference реализует перевод поинтера сразу в строку.

Comment: `var Msg: PChar` это **указатель на указатель** на тело строки, причём оно может быть как в ANSI-кодировке, так и в Unicode (в зависимости от версии Дельфи и настроек компилятора. Начиная с D2009 PChar=PWidechar, если не установлено AnsiChar в опциях). Но первое, с чем надо разбираться, наверное - это двойной указатель - ` реализует перевод поинтера сразу в строку.` это учитывает?

Comment: По поводу версии делфи не могу ответить от слова совсем ничего... Так как библиотека очень специфична и никакой более подробной инфы по ней нету... Вывод версии драйвера срабатывает при указании опции W32APIOptions.ASCII_OPTIONS при подгрузке, если указать UNICODE_OPTIONS, выдаёт китайские иероглифы, следовательно могу предположить  что это ANSI. По поводу двойного указателя можно поподробнее, пожалуйста, первый раз сталкиваюсь. Конкретно интересна реализация этого в JNA

Comment: В сях это выглядит как `**char`, а нужно это - потому что адрес строки может измениться . Про jna ничего не могу сказать.

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо за подсказку, попробую что то нарыть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И так, проблема решена. В комментариях [MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659/mbo) подсказал по поводу двойного указателя, решил проблему следующим образом.
Интерфейс:

```
CscLink INSTANCE = (CscLink) Native.loadLibrary("csclink", CscLink.class, W32APIOptions.ASCII_OPTIONS);
boolean GetAccountMessage(int Account, PointerByReference Msg);
```

main:

```
//объявляем переменные
String msg;
Pointer point;
PointerByReference getAccMsg;
//Инициализируем
       getAccMsg = new PointerByReference();
//выполняем вызов функции из DLL
       myLib.GetAccountMessage(getAccNumb.getValue(), getAccMsg);
//Инициализируем указатель референсным указателем (если так можно назвать)
       point = getAccMsg.getValue();
//В строку передаём указатель с вызовом строки и началом памяти
       msg = point.getString(0);
```

После этого в строке `msg` получаем нужный нам ответ.